# Error in parsing XML file from mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, encoding, escaping

i am working with jsp server,mysql database and xsl transformations. I have a link from an xml file stored to my pc so as to translate it  with xslt.If i do this and everything is fine:

```
String url="c:\\xampp\\tomcat\\webapps\\examples\\sakias.xml";
Document doc = builder.parse(new File(url)); and so on as usual...
```

The problem is that if i store the url link (`c:\\xampp\\tomcat\\webapps\\examples\\sakias.xml`) in a column to mysql database and then fetch it i get the following error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:///c:/xampp/; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog
```

Is there a problem with encoding;escape characters; It is really weird.

PS1:Is there an another solution to store xml directly into sql database;My version does not support xml field.Can i store it escaped as String;

PS2: I changed the url link to this form(http://localhost:8080/examples/jsp/jsp2/loginrecord/link_error.xml) but still the same error. I print it and it is fine but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your URL in the database should not have the `\` escaped. It should look like `c:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\examples\sakias.xml`

Also, yes, you can store XML in SQL database. You shouldn't have to worry about escaping it for storage (you may need to escape it if you're constructing the string in Java), but you should worry about column sizes. You might choose to store it as TEXT instead of VARCHAR (there's no such thing as String SQL type).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have tried both of your  suggestions but it didn't worked. In the second suggestion i get "Premature end of file error".

Comment: @sakias MySQL can truncate data if it doesn't fit into a field, which may give you that error. Check that your column size is large enough.